# How do I make a subsection title visible in a header on page with chapter / section

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, chapters

Could someone please give me a hand to correctly use `\markboth{}{}` within redefinition of the `\sectionmark`? I am struggling to apply the second parameter in `\markboth`. The article I am writing needs to have both section and subsection titles on all pages. I read [Header not displaying correctly on chapter page due to subsection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79664/header-not-displaying-correctly-on-chapter-page-due-to-subsection) and understood that `\chapter` or `\section` commands make the `\markright` field empty and therefore subsection does not appear on pages where `\chapter` or `\section` is issued. I still cannot understand how to make this work. I will be grateful for any help.

PS. Below is the LaTeX code. I am compiling the article using XeLaTeX.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\special{papersize=210mm,297mm}

\title{\bfseries Factor Analysis}
\author{J. Smith}

% Set font
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Cambria}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}

% if then
\usepackage{ifthen}

\usepackage[a4paper,portrait,hmargin=2.54cm,vmargin=2.54cm,bindingoffset=0cm,includehead,includefoot]{geometry} % Document margins
\geometry{headheight=14pt}

% Multi columns
%\usepackage{paralist} % Used for the "compactitem" environment which makes bullet points with less space between them
\usepackage{multicol} % Used for the two-column layout of the document
\setlength{\columnsep}{20pt}

% Fancy headers
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancy} % All pages have headers and footers
\fancyhf{} % clear all headers and footers - equivalent to %\fancyhead{} and \fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\newcommand{\mymarks}{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\rightmark}{}} % is \rightmark empty?
        {\leftmark} % when empty
        {\leftmark\ --\ \itshape\rightmark} % when not empty
}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\fancyhead[C]{\mymarks} % Custom header text
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} % Custom footer text

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url} % allows escaping special characters inside a hyper links in a bibliography such as %20 etc.
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[format=hang,font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} % Custom captions under/above floats in tables or figures

% Links in PDF
%\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    bookmarks=false,         % show bookmarks bar?
    pdftoolbar=true,        % show Acrobat’s toolbar?
    pdfmenubar=true,        % show Acrobat’s menu?
    pdffitwindow=false,     % window fit to page when opened
    pdfstartview={FitH},    % fits the width of the page to the window
    pdftitle={Exposure response relationship to noise in the presence of vibration},    % title
    pdfauthor={Zbigniew Koziel},     % author
    pdfsubject={Environmental Noise and Vibration},   % subject of the document
    pdfcreator={Zbigniew Koziel},   % creator of the document
    pdfproducer={Zbigniew Koziel}, % producer of the document
    pdfkeywords={noise} {vibration} {exposure response-relationship}, % list of keywords
    pdfnewwindow=true,      % links in new window
    colorlinks=true,
    citecolor=blue,
    linkcolor=red,      % color of internal links (change box color with linkbordercolor)
    urlcolor=blue,
    filecolor=black      % color of file links
}

% Change default commands
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}

% New commands
\newcommand{\defaultvspacing}{\doublespacing}
\newcommand{\compactvspacing}{\onehalfspacing}
\newcommand{\tidyvspacing}{\singlespacing}
\newcommand{\myterm}[2]{$#1_{\mathrm{#2}}$}
\newcommand{\defvspace}{12pt}
\newcommand{\clearthepage}{\clearpage} % depending on one or two side
\newcommand{\mysection}[2]{\clearthepage\markright{#2}\section{#1}}

\begin{document}
\tidyvspacing
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
    The abstract
\end{abstract}
\tableofcontents

\compactvspacing
\include{introduction}
\include{conceptual_view}
\include{fa_and_sm}
\include{the_factor_model}
\include{interpeting_factor_tables}

\bibliography{thesis} % Here from this place, the Bibliography should appear !
% \bibliographystyle{plain} % Standard commands for BiBTeX
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % Extended commands from package natbib
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the problem with marks for short sections and subsections is a well known problem with LaTeX marks. If you are willing to use another package, here's a solution using [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) with its options `pagestyles` and `extramarks` (I removed parts of the original code that were not relevant to the problem discussed):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[pagestyles,extramarks]{titlesec}

\settitlemarks*{section,subsection}

\newpagestyle{mystyle}{
\headrule\footrule
\sethead{}{\thesection.\ \sectiontitle\ifthesubsection{\ --\ \itshape\firstextramarks{subsection}\subsectiontitle}{}}{}
\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}
}
\pagestyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section One}
\lipsum[4]
\subsection{Test Subsection One}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Test Section Two}
Some test text here

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this example. I am quite a beginner in LaTeX and I knew there was the titlesec package but I did not realise it could also work for settings headings footnotes.I understand that three parameters in both commands \sethead{}{}{} and \setfoot{}{}{} correspond to left, centre, and right parts of heading/footnote which are also left, centre and right aligned.

Comment: @ZikO yes, you are right about the meaning for the three arguments. There are also three optional arguments in case the `twoside` option is in use. `\sethead[even-left][even-center][even-right]{odd-left}{odd-center}{odd-right}`, and analogously for `\setfoot`.