# Putting sections and subsections in the page header

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, longtable, landscape

I am using `LaTeX` to display `landscape` `longtable`s. Due to the nature of the contents, I regularly have `section`s, `subsection`s, `subsubsection`s and I use `paragraph` to proxy `subsubsubsection`s (through `titlesec`). I also use `pdfpageattr` to rotate the page

Given the layout of the page and the width of all the `longtable`s in my real-world example (width not reflected in toy example below), I cannot display the headings/subheadings on the same page. What will happen is that the headings/subheadings will show like normal but then there will be a blank page that follows, and the longtable will come on the following page.

I want to fix this by placing the `section`/`subsection` in the header. In the example below I would like all 4 lines of `section`s/`subsection`s to be in the `header`. How do I do this?

My preference is for the headers to be in the left hand margin of the rotated page (so when I'm viewing the page on the 90 degree tilt, I can read the heading as normal without bending my head). But the correct answer could simply include the sections in the normal header location.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{lscape}  %Landscap pages
\usepackage{hyperref} %Clickable links
\hypersetup{ 
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}

\usepackage{titlesec} %paragraph as subsubsubsection
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % no line in header area
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}           % page number in "outer" position of footer line
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\hyperlink{contents}{Click here go back}} % other info in "inner" position of footer line

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{sec}
\subsection{subsec}
\subsubsection{subsubsec}
\paragraph{subsubsubsec}

\global\pdfpageattr\expandafter{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate 90}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{r}\caption{test} \tabularnewline
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}\tabularnewline
\hline
\endfirsthead\caption[]{\em (continued)} \tabularnewline
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}\tabularnewline
\hline
\endhead
\hline
\endfoot
\label{c}
$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline$1$\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm currently working on a LaTeX 3 answer to this, but check out the other answer. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122792/breadcrumb-hyperlink-header

Comment: Does this help?  http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79664/34618

Answer (score 3):

The `landscape` business is irrelevant for the problem. However, rather than changing `\pdfpageattr` yourself, it's better to load `pdflscape` that modifies the `landscape` environment to do the right thing.

Here's how you can do:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % no line in header area
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}  % page number in "outer" position of footer line
% other info in "inner" position of footer line
\fancyfoot[L]{\hyperlink{contents}{Click here go back}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection. #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsection. #1}}
\fancyhead[L]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  \leftmark\\
  \rightmark
  \end{tabular}%
}
\setlength{\headheight}{24pt}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\hypertarget{contents}{}\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\section{sec}
\subsection{subsec}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

However, due to inherent limitations of LaTeX's mark mechanism, the first subsection may not be shown in the page header where it appears.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a beautiful result manually. I used `\addcontentsline` to create invisible headings and subheadings, then used `\lhead{sectionname: \emph{subsectionname}}` to create the effect that I wanted.

This is more manual and less extensible but is acceptable for what I'm using it for.

If others have more automated solutions I will give them the correct answer.