# Rightmark of \subsection disappear when it's on the same page with \section

Tags: fancyhdr

In a two-sided article, I wish to show the current subsection name on the odd pages, and the current section name on even pages. Therefore I wrote

```
\fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark}
\renewcommand*{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\uppercase{#1}}{}}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsection~~#1}}
```

However, if `\section` and `\subsection` is on the same page, then the right mark disappear. I searched on this site and found the reason (in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/554269/194994)):

> \rightmark always use the first mark, so if you have to sections or subsections on a page, you will get the first.

Is there anyway to change this behavior, making the right mark always shows up?

Below is a MWE, as you can see, the right mark on the first page disappear.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark}
\renewcommand*{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\uppercase{#1}}{}}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsection~~#1}}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\section{Section One}
    \subsection{Subsection One}
        \blindtext[10]
\section{Section Two}
    \blindtext[3]
    \subsection{Subsection Two}
        \blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: you can get the last rightmark on a page with the extramarks package.

Comment: See this answer, on what is essentially the same problem, especially the last pasrt of the answer:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/585058/113546

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516938/why-doesnt-the-subsection-show-in-the-header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an often recurring problem, because the standard LaTeX marks interact with each other. Therefore the sectionmark hides the subsectionmark.
I have written a new package `extramarks2` to solve this. The package is not yet on CTAN, because I still have to write the documentation, and integrate that into the `fancyhdr` documentation. But you can download a beta version from [Github](https://github.com/pietvo/fancyhdr/tree/extramarks2): get the files README-extramarks2, extramarks2.sty and extramarks2-multicol.tex. With this package, the solution is

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{extramarks2}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\firstrightxmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\firstleftxmark}
\fancyfoot[c]{\thepage}
\renewcommand*{\sectionmark}[1]{\extramarksleft{\uppercase{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionmark}[1]{\extramarksright{\thesubsection~~#1}}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\section{Section One}
\subsection{Subsection One}
 \blindtext[10]
\section{Section Two}
 \blindtext[3]
\subsection{Subsection Two}
 \blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this! By the way, is `extramarks2` the package you mentioned in the comment of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/586470/is-it-possible-to-print-the-first-three-titles-on-every-page-in-the-footer?noredirect=1#comment1473886_586470)?

Comment: Yes, it's that package. I just finished it this week (actually, I made the last edit a few hours ago).