# Is it possible to print the first three titles on every page in the footer?

Tags: fancyhdr

Is it possible to print the first three titles (chapter, section for `book` and section, subsection for `article`) in the footer?

For example, a page like this:

[image]

should have a footer like:

[image]

(If there are only one or two then just print them, if there are more than three then print a `...` below, like the picture above)

Currently I only know about `\firstrightmark` or `\lastrightmark` provided by `extramarks`, which only stores the first or the last title. Is it possible to store three titles and print them?

Below is a hard-coded version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\textcolor{black!30}{%
        \begin{tabular}[t]{r}
            {\MakeUppercase{1 Test}}\\    % section
            {1.1 test}\\                  % subsection
            {1.2 test two}\\              % subsection
            $\cdots$
        \end{tabular}
    }%
    \!\rlap{\textcolor{gray!55}{$|$}~~\thepage}}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}
...
\subsection{test}
...
\subsection{test two}
...

\section{Test Two}
...

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would say possible but not trivial.

Comment: I am working on a package that makes this possible if you want the first and last subsection. Send me a PM if you want to try it out. The LaTeX marks mechanism isn't really able to give you "second" things, only first and last ones.