# Sections and subsections in headers

Tags: fancyhdr

I would like to have the current section and subsection in the header, page numbering in the center of the footer.

If there are two or more subsections on the same page, however, any subsection will not be shown.  I have tried a lot of tips from here and a lot of tips from Google but none help.

My class is article, one paged.

Comment: This is really hard to determine what you want.  If you could provide a MWE that would be great or a picture.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean 'one sided' instead of 'one paged'?

Comment: Is your problem the same as this one?
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/586066/rightmark-of-subsection-disappear-when-its-on-the-same-page-with-section

Comment: Yes, of course, one sided.

Answer (score 0):

The header consists of left, right, and center. So I am not sure this is possible My guess is that you could create a new command like `\newcommand{\R}{\section{R}}`, but I am not sure that is what you are looking for. I used a \Huge command for the section in the following example.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagestyle{headings}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\Huge{Section}}
\lhead{Guides and tutorials}
\cfoot{Page \thepage}

\begin{document}

\noindent Hello, here is some text without a meaning.  This text should 
show what a printed text will look like at this place.  If you 
read this text, you will get no information.  Really?  Is there 
no information?  


\end{document}
```